# How can I clone a git repository with python code?

Tags: git, python-2.7

I am new to Git.I want to clone my remote github repository (git://github.com/eltejaee/BIC2.git) with python script.I know that "dulwich" and "gitpython" are suitable but I couldn't clone or pull with them .What is the best python code to clone my remote github repository?

Answer (score 2):

There are several modules you can use [git-python](https://gitorious.org/git-python) or [pygit](https://gitorious.org/pygit/mainline)

If you just want to clone/pull then you can use system commands:

```
os.system("git clone ...")
os.system("git pull")
```

and if you want the output of the command as well I recommend you to use [subprocesses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

For Github you can use [python-github](https://github.com/jmoiron/python-github)

Answer (score 0):

There is a python wrapper for github

https://github.com/jmoiron/python-github

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very simple and straight forward. It doesn't even need the manual entry of paraphrase/password.

Here is my complete code:

```
import os
import sys

path        =   "/path/to/store/your/cloned/project" 
clone       =   "git://github.com/eltejaee/BIC2.git" 

os.system("sshpass -p your_password ssh user_name@your_lhost")
os.chdir(path) # Specifying the path where the cloned project has to be copied
os.system(clone) # Cloning

print "\n CLONED SUCCESSFULLY.! \n"
```